# Can you store any object in a Vertex's property?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

Could I store a Tuple or a Map as the value of a vertex's property in Neptune/gremlin?  I'm unsure where the relevant docs are.

I can't find it in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#w3aac12c20c10c13c31) or in the [Vertex Javadocs](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.4.1/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Vertex.html#property-org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty.Cardinality-java.lang.String-V-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neptune currently does not support Map or a List as a property value. This is documented in the official AWS docs.

Go [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html#gremlin-api-reference-features) > Look for Vertex Property Feature > Observe MapValues = False